# Compute the Fundamental Group of the Infinite Grid

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

Consider the space $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ constructed by taking a horizontal line at every integer on the $y$-axis and a vertical line at every integer on the $x$-axis.

I need to compute $\pi_1(G,b)$ where b is your favourite base point, but I haven't been able to make much progress. Help please!

[Edit: The Count pointed out that I should probably be more specific with what subset I'm talking about! The simplest definition I can think of is $G=(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R})\cup(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z})$]

Comment: It would be very helpful to potential helpers if you defined everything clearly, as at the level of your question the subtle differences in notation and definitions matter. Just an FYI. Great first question, BTW.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014415/automorphism-group-of-covering-space-of-figure-eight-s1-vee-s1-given-by-t?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you know, here are hints that go in different directions.

Hint 1: take a spanning tree then use the fact that the remaining edges correspond to generators.  Said differently, when you have a graph you can contract a spanning tree to get a homotopy equivalent space that is a bouquet of circles.

Hint 2: This grid is the universal abelian cover of $S^1\vee S^1$.  That is, consider the covering space map $p:G\to S^1\vee S^1$, and recognize that the abelianization of $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and that the deck transformation group $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)/p_*(\pi_1(G))$ is observably $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so $p_*(\pi_1(G))$ is the commutator subgroup of the free group $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$.